# HTML distroting while Reloading browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using React with styled-component.

While I click on the browser reload button my HTML getting distorting for a second.

I try to debug it but componentWillUnmount is not getting called when click on browser reload.

SO My questions are:
Which react method called when we click on browser reload? 
How to debug this?

Comment: It could be happening as the style maybe taking time to load. Try to optimise the style load. You can load the bare minimum style first and the remaining later

Comment: To answer your question, the only method that is called is the browser's native `window.onbeforeunload`, which doesn't really help here.

Comment: this might be an issue with your `overflow` property. By distorting i believe you are seeing a scrollbar for a second then your UI loads with some CSS. Can you please elaborate more about it

Comment: @nmak18 It is happening before initializing main App.tsx file

Comment: @mkamranhamid Yes. the scroll is removing while I am refreshing page. How I can solve this any Idea?

Comment: then its related to css and maybe you have set container's height. Try changing height to `auto`.